# Customize link.title in facebook opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Ok I've successfully posted to my fb wall. I've created a link object as an action type in the opengraph dashboard. What I want to do now is to set the link.title to a string of my choosing.

Right now, what I think is happening is that fb is pulling the title of the link. I want to customize it.

Also, fb checks if the link is live or not so if I give a link to my localhost dev server, it doesn't show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is for people with the same problem as I had. The thing is that you have to have meta tags in the page that the link leads to (could be redirections).

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Hello World!"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.somesite.com/image1.jpg"/>
```

One thing to remember is that facebook will independently follow the link your app posted so make sure to handle those things. In my case, the link that I posted wouldn't work if a user wasn't logged in, so when fb came to check the link, it would be redirected to the login page and fb couldn't pull my title and images.

I handled this by checking for a query_string fb_action_ids. When fb automatically checks the link, the above query_string won't be set, but when the user clicks on the link, the query_string will be set.

Good Luck!